# java: Splitting arithmetic expresssion into tokens

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

How do you separate an arithmetic expression with space, example i have this expression 22+(33*1) i want to split them with space between operators in the same string (returning a String) like 22 + ( 33 * 1 ) by the way im using StringTokenizer

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yep tried using StringTokenizer with and separated "" with " " but its result is 2 2 + ( 3 3 * 1 ) it is seperated every digit, i just want to seperate it per operand like the one i stated above

Comment: an inefficient way would be to replace every token with itself followed by a space (using `String.replaceAll`) then split the string with a regex of `\x20+` (using `String.split`). Quick and dirty, but might meet your requirements.

Comment: Why? The meaning is the same either way. Or is this a step towards scanning and parsing the expression? In which case *that* is the question you should ask, and adding spaces has nothing to do with it.

Comment: to put it simply i just want to format the string like the one i said above

Comment: @lemoncodes I suggest that either the requirement is wrong or you have misunderstood it. Scanning and parsing do not require insertion of redundant spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is simpler then you think. Probably correct java:

```
expr = expr.replaceAll('+', ' + ')
           .replaceAll('-', ' - ')
           .replaceAll(')', ' ) ')
           //etc
           .replaceAll(' ', '  '); //remove any double spaces added.
```

Comment: Does not work when there are already spaces in the original expression. you would introduce additinal ones. (Which could be eliminated afterwards)

Comment: this is is the closes to what i did, although not really the same code but the idea is there

Answer (score 0):

That is Not Easy. You have to parse the Expression and 
Build up a tree of tokens. You Finally behave like 
A parser. Then you recreate the Expression and insert a Space between 
Each element. 

 try to search for parsing arithmetic expressions

Comment: Once he has the tree it's hard to see why he would then want to go back to a linear string at all. Strange question.

Comment: Yes strange, the motivation is missing

Comment: im not building a tree, im just separating each operand and operator with a whitespace, building a tree is for the later part of my program, im just building it up ready for the tree part, to put it simply i just want to speratre operand and operator with a whitespace basically its just string not any other strcuture

Comment: Inserting spaces will not help your later part. Skip your question and start with the later part.

Comment: i really hope i can do that but the requirements says otherwise.

Comment: Then either you or the person who wrote the req is wrong! Dont hesitate to doubt the req.

Comment: hehe naahh its part of the training actually, how to cope with hardheaded clients :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `String.replaceAll` statements to replace operators with operators with spaces.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't *need* multiple `replaceAll` expressions. It can be done with a single one, using a bit of regex and replacement magic.